# Can I use escape sequences like '&nbsp;' solely for styling purposes?

Tags: html

I had a situation where I needed to make some space between an icon and text so I used `&nbsp;`, this solved my issue but my lead said not to use escape sequences for styling. Can you guys please provide me with your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would apply styling through means of… well… styling?! Meaning CSS…?!

Comment: I would suggest trusting your lead on this one.